# How to start my own server as a service using systemd

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I have written my own server in Qt with QtWebApp

Now I want start that server on Ubuntu 15.10 startup using systemd

I created this service file

```
[Unit]
Description=This service maintains a landports server...
After=syslog.target
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=~/LandportsServer
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and when I run `sudo systemctl start landports`

systemd outputs `systemd Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)`

I changed my service file to be

```
[Unit]
Description=This service maintains a landports server...

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart= /home/wbmanager/LandportsServer

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

but when I run `sudo systemctl start landports`

nothing happen and no output is shown, and when I try to connect to my server using a browser connection fails, so the server is not running

I have tested my server before by running it through **ssh** and it works. But I can't get it working as a service

after waiting systemd outputs:

```
Jan 04 22:57:25 yassermyweb LandportsServer[4902]: Pattern handler and tokens:  HttpRequestHandler(0x1018790) ("recent", ":portID")
Jan 04 22:57:25 yassermyweb LandportsServer[4902]: added pattern for path: recent/:portID
Jan 04 22:57:25 yassermyweb LandportsServer[4902]: RootHandler 0xffe820: registering handlers...
Jan 04 22:57:25 yassermyweb LandportsServer[4902]: Pattern handler and tokens:  HttpRequestHandler(0x10183a0) ("")
Jan 04 22:57:25 yassermyweb LandportsServer[4902]: added pattern for path:
Jan 04 22:57:25 yassermyweb LandportsServer[4902]: HttpListener: Listening on port 0
Jan 04 22:58:55 yassermyweb systemd[1]: landports.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jan 04 22:58:55 yassermyweb systemd[1]: Failed to start This service maintains a landports server from the point the system is started until it is shut down again..
Jan 04 22:58:55 yassermyweb systemd[1]: landports.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 04 22:58:55 yassermyweb systemd[1]: landports.service: Failed with result 
'timeout'.
```

**Note that** lines starting with *Pattern handler and tokens:  HttpRequestHandler(0x1018790) ("recent", ":portID")*

are the output of mu=y server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is `ExecStart=~/LandportsServer`. Use the absolute path instead. Which home directory is systemd supposed to use anyway? It's running as root.

Another problem may be that you have configured the service as `Type=forking`. Change that to `Type=simple` (or comment that line out).

Comment: I modified the service to use full path, see my question I have edited it

Comment: @YasserSobhy Are you sure your process forks?

Comment: No I am not sure, I don't even know what is fork, I removed Type=forking and edited service description to remove last dot(it might cause parsing errors), and it worked, Thanks @HaukeLaging

Comment: @YasserSobhy Daemons (or their start programs) fork e.g. to put themselves in the background. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)